# an algorithm for clustering visually separable clusters

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, visualization, distance, pca

I have visualized a dataset in 2D after employing PCA. 1 dimension is time and the Y dimension is First PCA component. As figure shows, there is relatively good separation between points (A, B). But unfortunately clustering methods (DBSCAN, SMO, KMEANS, Hierarchical)  are not able to cluster these points in 2 clusters. As you see in section A there is a relative continuity and this continuous process is finished and Section B starts and there is rather big gap in comparison to past data between A and B.

I will be so grateful if you can introduce me any method and algorithm (or devising any metric from data considering its distribution) to be able to do separation between A and B without visualization. Thank you so much.

[image: Mentioned Figure - Plot of points]

This is plot of 2 PCA components for the above plot(the first one). The other one is also the plot of components of other dataset which I get bad result,too. 
[image: Plot of PCA compnents-bad results]

[image: Plot of PCA components for another dataset-bad results]

Answer (score 2):

This is a **time series**, and apparently you are looking for **change points** or want to **segment** this time series.

Do *not* treat this data set as a two dimensional x-y data set, and don't use clustering here; rather choose an algorithm that is actually designed for time series.

As a starter, plot `series[x] - series[x-1]`, i.e. the first derivative. You may need to **remove seasonality** to improve results. No clustering algorithm will do this, they do not have a notion of seasonality or time.

Comment: Thank you Anony-Mousse. Sharp like always! Actually The section A represents normal points and section B represents somehow outlier or let say abnormal ones. Now, I should be able to separate them in an unsupervised manner with PC components. PC components have good separation in some datasets but not so good in some others like this one. Can you explain more to handle this distribution and be able to reach a relative separation ?

Comment: Remove seasonality first!

Comment: Post is updated. The earlier plot was time plot of first component of PCA. I certainly don't mean to have best result. There are 2045 normal points and 200 abnormal. Having for example about100-120 points of B in one cluster will be so good and enough for me for these 2 datasets.

Comment: Don't neglect time. Use a method that *uses* seasonality and time instead for *better* results.

Comment: I have not used time-series at all. Can you name some methods to follow? You mean I should add time as a new feature to PCA components then use clustering and other unsupervised method?

Answer (score 1):

If PCA gives you a good separation, you can just try to cluster after projecting your data through your PCA eigenvectors. If you don't want to use PCA, then you will need anyway an alternative data projection method, because failing clustering methods imply that your data is not separable in the original dimensions. You can take a look at non linear clustering methods such as the kernel based ones or [spectral clustering](https://charlesmartin14.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/spectral-clustering/) for example. Or to define your own non-euclidian metric,  which is in fact just another data projection method.

But using PCA clearly seems to be the best fit in your case (Occam razor : use the simplest model that fits your data).

Comment: Thank you. I want to use PCA. Can you explain more. Because I employ clustering on PCA components but don't get desired result.

Comment: Are your learning the PCA projection on the first dataset (the one where this gives you good results) and then just apply the projection (without learning!) on the second, harder, dataset? If this doesn't help you, then indeed you should either look at Spectral Clustering, or as Anony-Mousse said into time series, because clearly you should learn a temporal repetitive motif (A) that can sometimes break (B, the anomalies).

Comment: Thank you. Please consider the second and third plot. The x and y axis are PCA components (PC 1 and PC2). Do you know any good and exact tool for testing spectral? I found some Matlab code but they didn't have good results and were like other clustering methods on these 2 datasets (2 and 3).

Comment: Yes I saw the 2nd and 3rd plot, and that's why I asked you: did you generate the 3rd plot by using the PCA learnt on the 2nd plot, or did you generate a new PCA projection?
About spectral clustering, you should look into [scikit-learn spectral clustering algorithms](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=scikit-learn+spectral), I didn't use them but they seem quite good and nicely explained. Also here is [a pretty good tutorial on spectral clustering](https://charlesmartin14.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/spectral-clustering/).

Comment: No. 2nd and 3rd plot are for two different datasets. Both of them are visualization of PCA components of related dataset.

Comment: Is the 3rd plot dataset from the same population/distribution as the 2nd plot (with the same features etc. only the sample being different), or they are totally different populations?

Comment: they share normal points (2045 points) but they are different in abnormal ones (200 points). The features are same but as mentioned in 200 samples values are different

Comment: Ok then the first thing you should try should be to learn/fit the PCA projection on the dataset of the 2nd plot, and then try to use this projection to project the dataset of the 3rd plot. Do not fit the PCA on the 3rd plot, fit it only with the dataset of the 2nd plot. In other words, to project the 3rd plot's dataset you just need to do a matrix multiplication to reduce the input features to the 2 main eigenvectors that you learnt in the 2nd plot. Please then report back the result here, it might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you'll have an easy time devising an algorithm to handle this case, which is dangerously (by present capabilities) close to "read my mind" clustering.  You have a significant alley where you've marked the division.  You have one nearly as good around (1700, +1/3), and an isolate near (1850, 0.45).  These will make it hard to convince a general-use algorithm to make exactly one division at the spot you want, although that one is (I think) still the most computationally obvious.

Spectral clustering works well at finding gaps; I'd try that first.  You might have to ask it for 3 or 4 clusters to separate the one you want in general.  You could also try playing with SVM (good at finding alleys in data), but doing that in an unsupervised context is the tricky part.

No, KMeans is not going to work; it isn't sensitive to density or connectivity.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can you explain a bit more about Spectral clustering? I have not used them till now.

Comment: If you have a particular question *after* you've done the initial investigation, then I'll happily try to explain.  However, StackOverflow is not a tutorial site: we expect *you* to do that initial research and come here with specific questions.  "explain a bit more" is too open-ended.

Comment: You are right. I heard  spectral for the first time. Actually I had encountered it  before but didn't the name. I'm looking for a good tool for this issue and I couldn't find any good one(except some invalid Matlab code). Is there anyone?

Comment: The only one with which I'm familiar is the one for which I did quality assurance, Intel's Trusted Analytics Platform / Analytics Tool Kit.  However, TAP has more overhead than you'll likely want to set up.  Last I knew, Apache's MLlib didn't implement that algorithm, but that may have changed since I last looked in February.